# Insert into table with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to insert data from a form into a database using PHP and Mysqli but I can't get it working! My database has 4 fields: DATE, TITLE, CONTENT, ID. The ID field is auto-increment.

I've checked the connection and that's working fine. I've also echoed the form field values and the $blogDate variable I created, they're all fine too.

Here's my prepared statement:

```
if ($newBlog = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO Blog VALUES ($blogDate, $_POST["bTitle"], $_POST["bContent"])')) {
  $newBlog->execute();
  $newBlog->close();
}
```

It's just not inserting the values into my table.

Comment: using prepare is useful only when you parametrize it, in your query; you directly injected untrusted user data...

Comment: You need to use a prepared statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are generating SQL containing strings that are not quoted or escaped.

Don't insert the data directly into the SQL string, use placeholders (`?`) and then bind the parameters before executing.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Blog VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $blogDate, $_POST["bTitle"], $_POST["bContent"]);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Aaaah right I see! I'll give that a go. I'm new to PHP so don't know much about all this.

Comment: What is the role of "sss" in: $stmt->bind_param("sss", $blogDate, $_POST["bTitle"], $_POST["bContent"]); ?

Comment: Where can I get it from?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are aware about prepared statement:

```
$newBlog = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO Blog (`dateCol`, `titleCol`, `contentCol`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$newBlog->bind_param( 'sss', $blogDate, $_POST["bTitle"], $_POST["bContent"] );
$newBlog->execute();
$newBlog->close();
```

Comment: Fantastic, this is even more helpful with the code snippet. Thanks, it's working now. Only other thing I'm wondering here about prepared statements: In the PHP manual they wrap prepared statements in an if statement. Do I need to do that here? If so, I don't know why.

Comment: @Coop You can chose to wrap them in an if-statement. It'll be helpful if you want to handle the errors on your own.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using auto increment field you need to specify column name and then values
try this code

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Blog (colname_1,colname_2,colname_3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $blogDate, $_POST["bTitle"], $_POST["bContent"]);
$stmt->execute();
```